# setting the first element value with iloc

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['a','a','a','b'],"item1":['b','d',np.nan,'c']})
```

The content of df

```
  item item1
0    a     b
1    a     d
2    a   NaN
3    b     c
```

I want to change the second element value of "item" to 1, the following does not work

```
df.iloc[0,"item"]="b"
```

My expected output is:

```
  item item1
0    a     b
1    1     d
2    a   NaN
3    b     c
```

What's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `item`, so possible set value in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc("item")] = 1
```

Or by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#if any unique index
df.loc[df.index[1], "item"] = 1

#if default index
df.loc[1, "item"] = 1
```

---

```
print (df)
  item item1
0    a     b
1    1     d
2    a   NaN
3    b     c
```